# How to setup a Route 53 DNS record in front of three other records?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, round-robin

I have a zone in Route 53; let's call it `example.com`. I have three A records in that zone:

```
server1.example.com  --> elastic_ip_1
server2.example.com  --> elastic_ip_2
server3.example.com  --> elastic_ip_3
```

I want to add a *new* record to Route 53 with the name `server.example.com` so that a DNS lookup of `server.example.com` will return one of the three Elastic IP's listed above, chosen randomly and with equal probability.

How do I add this new record?

(Note: these services are UDP-based, so we cannot use the Elastic Load Balancer.)

UPDATE: I would prefer not to use an A record with multiple IP addresses as this would have to be updated each time one of the underlying A records changes.

Comment: Perhaps you need to edit your question to include more big picture. It seems like you're trying to manually create a load balancer in a weird way.  You can do this using ELB or Route53.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.loggly.com/blog/why-aws-route-53-over-elastic-load-balancing/) and [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-udp-load-balancing/). Short version: Route53 or Nginx can do it. The reason ELB can't do UDP is it's based on HAProxy, which doesn't support UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [weighted resource record set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted), giving all the records the same weight.

Each record would be of type `A`, but with `Alias` set to `Yes`.  The alias target for each of the new records would be one of the existing `A` records, each of which (in this case) must be another record that is already present, and in the same hosted zone.

This configuration also allows you to use Route 53 health checks to evaluate the health of each record's target, and exclude any unhealthy resources from the responses Route 53 will return.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-weighted-alias.html

Answer (score 2):

Just add all three of those IPs to the A record, like this:
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this where you instead put in the names of the A records of the Elastic IPs: `server1.example.com`, `server2.example.com`, `server3.example.com`. This way if the IP address of `server1.example.com` changes in the future, you would not have to worry about updating the record for `server.example.com` (subject to TTL).

Comment: You would do that with a CNAME RR but you can have only one of those RRs.

Answer (score 0):

So , you maybe use PowerShell

Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA –Name example –IPv4Address ip_address –ZoneName your_domain

Resolve-DnsName example+your_domain

Answer (score 0):

I think this was what Michael - sqlbot was getting at; here are the details that worked for me.

I created three "alias" A records each with the same name: `server.example.com`:

```
Name                Type  Value                      Weight  Set ID
server.example.com  A     ALIAS server1.example.com  10      wwr1
server.example.com  A     ALIAS server2.example.com  10      wwr2
server.example.com  A     ALIAS server3.example.com  10      wwr3
```

There were two things that confused me: the records all use the *same* name (i.e., `server.example.com`), and that the Set ID's are all *different*.

(This post was also helpful: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=126148)